# applescript choose list in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, applescript

I'm having difficulty launching a simple applescript choice list from a shell script. I have no issue launching dialog boxes to capture user input in the same way within my shell script.  For whatever reason, the command below works inconsistently, the first call always times out.  Subsequent calls with the same syntax sometimes work, sometimes don't.  I get the same behavior when I run the command independent of the script within a bash shell - first execution times out, subsequent runs eventually work and display the choose list.  It's driving me nuts, what am I missing!  Thanks!

```
osascript -e 'Tell application "System Events" to return choose from list {"Students", "Faculty-Staff"}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`choose from list` is part of Standard Additions. It's not related to `System Events`

```
osascript -e 'return choose from list {"Students", "Faculty-Staff"}'
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was something that simple.  Thanks for the quick response!